# Calling unlock on a mutex associated with a unique_lock causes undefined behavior

Tags: multithreading, c++11, std, mutex, critical-section

I wrote a simple code where I take a unique_lock and unlock the mutex instead of calling unlock on the lock itself. When the first thread enters the critical section and calls my_mutex.unlock(), many other threads enter the critical section together.

```
std::mutex my_mutex;
void sample() {
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
   // Critical section
   my_mutex.unlock();
}
```

Why is this happening? Is it wrong to call unlock on a mutex held by a unique_lock? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UB is not caused by the explicit unlock using `std::mutex::unlock`, but by the second unlock that is performed by the `std::unique_lock` destructor when exiting the scope.

**From cppreference.com when calling `std::mutex::unlock`:**

> *The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*

The solution is to *not* perform the explicit unlock on the mutex. Instead let the `std::unique_lock` unlock itself upon destruction as is intended.

For cases where the lock needs to be released before destruction, use [`std::unique_lock::unlock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unlock) which will allow for safe destruction. Alternatively you can simply insert an additional scope, *e.g.*:

```
void sample() {
    // Before.
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
        // Critical section.
    }
    // After.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I didn't have a local mutex in my actual code. I will update the code in the question.